# Get absolute path from filename and pass into sendkeys

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a Python program that logs into a website, asks the user for a file name (ex: upload.tar), and then the program finds the absolute path of that file on my computer and passes that path to the site for uploading. I'm running into problems getting the program to search my entire computer for the file and pulling that absolute path into sendkeys.

I created a variable called `fileName = Path(input()).absolute()` and then tried to pass it to the site via `driver.find_element(By.ID, "root_file_upload").send_keys(fileName)` and got the below errors.

**Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home_dylanantonacci/Python/Programs/hepdata_uploader/hepd_uploadV2.py", line 53, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "root_file_upload").send_keys(fileName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 541, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 148, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'PosixPath' has no len()
```

**Here's my full code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from pathlib import Path
import os

def hepLogin(user, password, url):
    s = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(user)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']").click()

print("Enter your username: ")
user = input()
print("Enter your password: ")
password = input()

**##--Get absolute path from file name--##**
print("File name: ")
fileName = Path(input()).absolute()

url = "https://www.hepdata.net/login/"

hepLogin(user, password, url)

errors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible text-left']")

if any(errors):
        print("[!] Login failed")
else:
        print("[+] Login successful")

driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sandbox").click()
**##--Send the absolute path from findName to website--##**
driver.find_element(By.ID, "root_file_upload").send_keys(fileName)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Upload and Process']").click()
```

Comment: Use `.send_keys(str(fileName))` (or `fileName = str(Path(input()).absolute())`)

Comment: Hmmm so this searches for an absolute path, but only in the directly the program lives. I'm trying to get the program to search for the file across every directory.